# Openshift: fee layer adding cartridge to specific gear

Tags: mysql, openshift

All examples i have seen concerning add cartridges is always to the same gear ass app
As in free layer we have 3 gears can we have an non-scallable app in one gear and mysql in other gear?
If yes, how to add mysql cartridge to other gear?

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 0):

Every application that you create must contain one web framework cartridge, such as ruby, php, java, etc.  If you want MySQL to be on it's own gear, then you need to create a scaled application, and when you add the database, it will go onto it's own gear, that will be part of your scaled application.